# Vue prevent on component link not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have
component tag:

```
<template>
    <a href="url">hi</a>
</template>
```

On other page i show tag and want call my method on mouseClick

```
<tag @click.prevent="myFunction"></tag>
```

But i get redirect to url. **Prevent modificator dont work**. How fix this ?

**Update:**

Equal question but if change html 'A' to vue router link

```
<template>
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'OtherPage'}"></router-link>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Binding Native Events to Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)

> There may be times when you want to listen directly to a native event on the root element of a component. In these cases, you can use the .native modifier for v-on:

Just add `.native` modifier to your component to get the native behavior you'r expecting.

```
<tag @click.native.prevent="myFunction"></tag>
```

```js
const Tag = Vue.component('Tag', {
  template: '<a href="http://url.com">My Link</a>',
  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components:{
    Tag
  },
  methods:{
    myFunction(){
        alert(`Won't redirect you`)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <tag @click.native.prevent="myFunction"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thx. its work!  I add 'update' in question about router-link. With router-link your solution dont work

Comment: With router it's not the same problem neither the same behavior, you should open a new question ... Mean while take a look at this issues https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/916

Answer (score 1):

You code is not working because you add a listener on `tag` component not `a` element.

> Using the `$listeners` property, you can forward all event listeners on the component to a specific child element with `v-on="$listeners"`

Read [more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

Example code:

```html
<div id='app'>
  <tag url='/abc' text='Click Me' @click.prevent='myFunction'></tag>
</div>
```

and

```html
<template>
  <a :href='url' v-on='$listeners'>{{ text }}</a>
</template>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lezr5os/)

Comment: thx for solution. With ''.native.prevent' more clear code :)